# How can I pass values from a function to SVG tag?

Tags: javascript, function, svg, modular

I want to make the header of my application dynamically and modular, so I'm writing a function in Javascript that will color the header (SVG) dynamically, but how can I include SVG into my function (such as: `document.getElementByTagName(SVG)` or something?).

This is for an webapp, I want to make a function `headerStyle(title, pageSVG1, pageSVG2, pageSVG3)`, which will style the header, with the correct SVG formats and colors which are passed into the function. For example: `headerstyle('Menu', 'FF0000', '000000', 'D3D3D3')`. I'm not sure how to begin to set up this function.

```
<svg width="100%" height="262" viewBox="0 0 375 262" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <circle cx="188" cy="-803" r="1065" fill="FF0000"/>
        <path d="M1046.5 -839.5C1046.5 -251.317 569.683 225.5 -18.5 225.5C-606.683 225.5 -1083.5 -251.317 -1083.5 -839.5C-1083.5 -1427.68 -606.683 -1904.5 -18.5 -1904.5C569.683 -1904.5 1046.5 -1427.68 1046.5 -839.5Z" fill="000000"/>
        <path d="M652 -635.5C652 -156.393 263.607 232 -215.5 232C-694.607 232 -1083 -156.393 -1083 -635.5C-1083 -1114.61 -694.607 -1503 -215.5 -1503C263.607 -1503 652 -1114.61 652 -635.5Z" fill="D3D3D3"/>
        <text id="page-title" style="fill: white; font-size: 28px; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; padding: 50px;" x="50" y="120">Menu</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Ìnto the function:

```
function headerStyle(title, pageSVG1, pageSVG2, pageSVG3) {
    document.getElementByTagName("SVG");
}
```

I honestly don't know how I'm gonna get it working. Could you please help or show me an example of how I can achieve this? 
If passed `headerStyle("Menu", "FF00000", "000000", "D3D3D3")`, I want to get the color of the first circle `#FF00000`, the second `#000000`, but I don't know how I can write a function like that. The output is not what it should be.

Comment: You have to remove `fill="none"`, and if you need a function to change the color you can do: `function headerStyle(svg,color){svg.setAttribute("style",`fill:${color}`)}`

Comment: I want the elements into the <g> tag to be colored, so <circle> and <path>. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As I've told you in my comment you need to remove `fill="none"`. Then you can write a function to change the style of the SVG element like this.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");

function headerStyle(svg,color){svg.setAttribute("style",`fill:${color}`)}

headerStyle(svg,"gold")
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="262" viewBox="0 0 375 262" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <circle cx="188" cy="-803" r="1065" fill="FF0000"/>
        <path d="M1046.5 -839.5C1046.5 -251.317 569.683 225.5 -18.5 225.5C-606.683 225.5 -1083.5 -251.317 -1083.5 -839.5C-1083.5 -1427.68 -606.683 -1904.5 -18.5 -1904.5C569.683 -1904.5 1046.5 -1427.68 1046.5 -839.5Z" fill="000000"/>
        <path d="M652 -635.5C652 -156.393 263.607 232 -215.5 232C-694.607 232 -1083 -156.393 -1083 -635.5C-1083 -1114.61 -694.607 -1503 -215.5 -1503C263.607 -1503 652 -1114.61 652 -635.5Z" fill="D3D3D3"/>
        <text id="page-title" style="fill: white; font-size: 28px; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; padding: 50px;" x="50" y="120">Menu</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> But what if I want to change the fill of the  inside the  tag or the fill of the  tag inside the  tag?

In this case you need to select the circle or/and the path and change the fill for those:

```
let circle = document.querySelector("circle");
circle.setAttribute("style",`fill:${color}`);
```

You can also change the function to something like:

```
function changeStyle(svgElmt,color){svgElmt.setAttribute("style",`fill:${color}`)}
```

Now you can use the function for the any svg element:

```
changeStyle(circle,"red")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what if I want to change the fill of the <circle> inside the <g> tag or the fill of the <path> tag inside the <g> tag?

Comment: Now, i understand it! And how can I target the two <path> elements with querySelector, because they have the same type?

Comment: If you need to target 2 path elements you may use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)